# Pass Value from one page to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass form value from one html page to another html page.

I wonder Is that possible to pass values between html page not using server side code.

And if not, how can i pass values?
(I prefer to not use server side...)

Here is some my project code :

**First HTML page**

```
 <form id="myForm" method="post" action="secondHTMLPage URL">
      <input type="hidden" id="UserID" name="UserID" value="12345">
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#myForm").submit();
 </script>
```

**Second HTML page**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      // In here, I want to retrieve my $("#myForm")'s data from First Page.
 </script>
```

Comment: Have a look into [Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) or [Session Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp)

Comment: @EGC no way to use only html and javascript, right? must use local storage?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to look into a type of data persistance.. I suppose the nasty way is to pass/collect individual attributes via the URL as params, but this isn't secure for your data and can end up with URLs so long you get HTML exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [**Window.sessionStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [**Window.localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

> The read-only `localStorage` property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions.
>
> `localStorage` is similar to `sessionStorage`, except that while data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration time, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.

Set value in one page

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
//using sessionStorage 
//sessionStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

Get the value in other page

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
//using sessionStorage 
//var cat = sessionStorage.getItem('myCat');
```